# Nginx TCP (WebSockets) Timeout / Keepalive Config

Tags: nginx, tcp, websocket

I am using `nginx version: nginx/1.0.12`

My nginx.conf looks like this:

```
#user  nobody;
worker_processes  1;  

error_log  logs/error.log;
#error_log  logs/error.log  notice;
#error_log  logs/error.log  info;

#pid        logs/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

tcp {

     upstream websockets {
      ## Play! WS location
       server 127.0.0.1:9000;
       check interval=3000 rise=2 fall=5 timeout=1000;
     }    

    server {
        listen 80; 
        listen 8000;
        server_name socket.domain.com;

        tcp_nodelay on; 
        proxy_pass websockets;
        proxy_send_timeout 300;

    }   

     # virtual hosting
     #include /usr/local/nginx/vhosts/*;
}
```

My application seems to be dropping websocket connnections every 75 sec (or so) which I think is because of Nginx's default keepalive config. How do increase the timeout?

Comment: Check [wiki](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_upstream_module.html#keepalive).

Comment: I had tried that earlier: I added keepalive 32 on line 20  (under server 127.0.0.1:9000) and I get nginx: [emerg] unknown directive "keepalive" in /usr/local/nginx/conf/nginx.conf:20

Comment: @DmitryPaskal, if I remove the upstream directive (I am not load balancing yet) and add a proxy pass in the server tag, then what should I do?

Comment: Did you added `proxy_http_version 1.1;` and `proxy_set_header Connection "";`? Read link carefully.

Comment: @DmitryPaskal - I tried following your notes but they seem to be for http and not for tcp. Updated nginx.conf (http://pastebin.com/NP9BhFrt) giving similar errors.

Comment: Oh, what's your nginx version?

Answer (score 71):

I tried the `websocket_*_timeout` which are not supported on nginx 1.7.1 (it gives: *unknown directive*).

However setting a high `proxy_*_timeout` works:

```
proxy_connect_timeout 7d;
proxy_send_timeout 7d;
proxy_read_timeout 7d;
```

`7d` means 7 days, see [official nginx configuration reference](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_connect_timeout)

Additionally you probably only have to set the `proxy_read_timeout 7d;` as that's the one that usually matter unless the server behind the proxy is very slow.

Comment: I tried the same, and it's working fine... But in Firebug (add on for Firefox), it's giving errors saying - "NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://localhost/......" and "Firefox can’t establish a connection to the server at ws://localhost/....."

Comment: The `websocket_*_timeout` requires nginx to be compiled with the `nginx_tcp_proxy_module` module from https://github.com/yaoweibin/nginx_tcp_proxy_module

Comment: Not sure you really want to set `proxy_connect_timeout` to such a long period as it's not used as a keepalive config. From the manual: `Defines a timeout for establishing a connection with a proxied server. It should be noted that this timeout cannot usually exceed 75 seconds.`

Comment: `proxy_read_timeout 7d;` should be enough. Don't mess `proxy_connect_timeout` config. It is important.

Comment: is this safe to keep `proxy_read_timeout` for `7d`? from performance/resources point of view?

Answer (score 9):

these brillant guys had the same problem and solved it ....

[NGINX to reverse proxy websockets AND enable SSL (wss://)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12102110/nginx-to-reverse-proxy-websockets-and-enable-ssl-wss)

also, here in the original repo for that module is more instructions from the module author.

https://github.com/yaoweibin/nginx_tcp_proxy_module/issues/28

it basically amounts to adding websocket_*_timeout instructions in the server directive:

```
 server {

     ....

     websocket_connect_timeout ######;
     websocket_send_timeout #####;
     websocket_read_timeout #####;

     ....

         }
```

Answer (score 0):

Other's answer is worked.

Just post offical websocket proxying notes here,
which help us understand more precisely about why and how.

http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/websocket.html

> By default, the connection will be closed if the proxied server does not transmit any data within `60 seconds`. This timeout can be increased with the `proxy_read_timeout` directive.
>
> Alternatively, the proxied server can be configured to periodically
> send WebSocket ping frames to reset the timeout and check if the
> connection is still alive.

http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_read_timeout

> Defines a timeout for reading a response from the proxied server. The timeout is set only between two successive read operations, not for the transmission of the whole response.
>
> If the proxied server does not transmit anything within this time, the connection is closed.

```
proxy_read_timeout 1d;
```